# How to make fake underline under when link click

Tags: css

I want to make something like below

```
  link1   link2   link3
```

when link1 is clicked

```
  link1   link2   link3

  _____
```

when link2 is clicked

```
  link1   link2   link3

          _____
```

I see this kind in different websites but not able to find something after searching. I found this one https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/stylish-a-styling-e80c80cbc30e but want to know if the one i posted can be made from the one in link.

Comment: What code have you tried and which is the actual effect you are looking for ? and yes, that can be done from a single <a> tag with various methods. Without any code and a clear question, you'll get downvoted/closed and get guesses for answers. there might even be a few duplicate already here :(

Comment: yes, see https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/06/creative-link-effects/ and demos are here https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/ this should fit your  question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**border-bottom**

A simple solution is using `border-bottom` on the `<a>` tags.

**pseudo elements**

The solution in your link uses pseudo elements. It is explained there; here is the result from that explanation, just with reversed widths:

```css
a {
  color: #0000ee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
    background-color: #0000ee;
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 0%;
}

a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` when the `active` class is added or on `focus` event.